# Variance and differential entropy

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, lp-spaces, entropy

Let $f:\mathbb R^d\to  [0,\infty)$ be a probability density function:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x)\,d x =1\,. $$
Suppose $f$ has finite second moment:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} |x|^2\,f(x)\,d x <\infty\,. $$
I have read that $f$ has then finite entropy:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} |\log f(x)|\,f(x)\,d x <\infty $$
but I am not sure how to prove this statement. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit.** I can prove the thesis adding the hypothesis $f(x)\leq c_0\,e^{c_1|x|^2}$ for every $x$. Indeed splitting the integral in three terms:
$$ \int_{\{f\geq1\}} \log f(x)\,f(x) \,d x \,\leq\, \log c_0 + c_1\int_{\mathbb R^d}|x|^2\,f(x) \,d x \,,$$
$$ \int_{\{f\leq e^{-|x|}\}} -\log f(x)\,f(x) \,d x \,\leq\, \int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{-\frac{|x|}{2}} \,d x \quad(\textrm{since } -f\,\log f\leq \sqrt{f} \textrm{ for }0\leq f\leq1)\,,$$
$$ \int_{\{e^{-|x|}<f<1\}} -\log f(x)\,f(x) \,d x \,\leq\, \int_{\mathbb R^d} |x|\,f(x)\,d x \;.$$
Is it possible to remove the hypothesis of $f$ being controlled by $e^{|x|^2}$?

Comment: As stated it is not true; you can take $d=1$ and choose an $f$ which is non-zero only on short intervals $[n,n+\epsilon_n]$ (with $\epsilon_n$ going to $0$ very fast as $n\to\infty$); $f$ can be say constant and very large (as $n\to\infty$) on each if these intervals. It is basically a reverse of your edit section.

Comment: @user8268 thanks for your comment. Are you sure that with your example one could still have $\int |x|^2 f(x)\,dx<\infty$ while $\int |\log f(x)| f(x)\,dx=\infty$ ? Would you like to write an answer with a suitable choice of $\epsilon_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, this result is not true. Take $d=1$, and let $f$ be $0$ everywhere except for intervals $[n,n+\epsilon_n]$ ($n=1,2,3\dots$) and let $f$ be equal to a constant $c_n$ on $[n,n+\epsilon_n]$. If say $c_n\epsilon_n=A/n^4$ (with $A=1/\zeta(4)=90/\pi^4$) then the second moment is finite.

If we choose $c_n=\exp(n^3)$ and so $\epsilon_n = A/(n^4\exp(n^3))$, then  $\int_{\mathbb R} |\log f(x)|\,f(x)\,d x = \sum_n A/n =\infty$.